# Opencart Empty Cart Problem When İ Log in the site

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I m adding some product to cart but my problem is starting when i log in the site my cart is empty

Comment: You need to give details like what OC version, what theme, what extensions etc.?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is with your session in `system/library/cart/cart.php`

After you have logged in, the customer class is initiated and the __construct method runs.

on `line 22` of the file `system/library/cart/cart.php` you can see how it works:

```php
// this code queries the current cart of your session id. so before you were logged int, your cart was saved to the database under a session id.
$cart_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cart WHERE api_id = '0' AND customer_id = '0' AND session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "'");

//after it finds your card products, it adds them to your CUSTOMER id.
foreach ($cart_query->rows as $cart) {
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cart WHERE cart_id = '" . (int)$cart['cart_id'] . "'");

    // The advantage of using $this->add is that it will check if the products already exist and increaser the quantity if necessary.
    $this->add($cart['product_id'], $cart['quantity'], json_decode($cart['option']), $cart['recurring_id']);
}
```

So the reason for not populating your cart after login is because in that session. It could be that some part of your code deletes the $this->session->getId() so the script can't find any products in cart.

To debug this just print_r the session_id and the results like this

```php
//print out the session id.
print_r($this->session->getId());
$cart_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cart WHERE api_id = '0' AND customer_id = '0' AND session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "'");

//print out the result of the query
print_r($cart_query->rows);
foreach ($cart_query->rows as $cart) {
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cart WHERE cart_id = '" . (int)$cart['cart_id'] . "'");

    // The advantage of using $this->add is that it will check if the products already exist and increaser the quantity if necessary.
    $this->add($cart['product_id'], $cart['quantity'], json_decode($cart['option']), $cart['recurring_id']);
}
```

to see that is in there. if it is empty, you will need to dig deeper to see who is deleting it.

if it is populated, visit the phpmyadmin table oc_cart to check to find the records of the `session_id=$this->session->getId()` and try to find out why it is not returning the cart products.

hope this helps.